# Dice Game // Loop not exiting properly when reached GAME_END_POINTS

Tags: python, debugging, dice

```
while(user_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS or computer_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS):
    print_current_player(is_user_turn)
    user_total = take_turn(is_user_turn,COMPUTER_HOLD)
    user_plcr = user_plcr + user_total
    is_user_turn = get_next_player(is_user_turn)
    print_current_player(is_user_turn)
    computer_total = take_turn(is_user_turn,COMPUTER_HOLD)
    computer_plcr = computer_plcr + computer_total
    report_points(user_plcr,computer_plcr)
    print("\n")
    is_user_turn = get_next_player(is_user_turn)

def take_turn(is_user_turn, COMPUTER_HOLD):
human_score = 0
computer_score = 0
if is_user_turn == True:
    begin = raw_input("roll? [yn]")
    if begin == 'y' or begin == 'Y':
        human_rand = roll_die()
    elif begin == 'n' or begin == 'N':
        is_user_turn = False
        return human_score
    while human_rand != 1:
        human_score = human_score + human_rand
        if human_score != 0:
            human_score = str(human_score)
            human_rand = str(human_rand)
            print("roll: " + human_rand)
            print("Current Score: " + human_score)
            human_rand = int(human_rand)
            human_score = int(human_score)
            again = raw_input("roll again? [yn]")
            print("\n")
            if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
                human_rand = roll_die()
                continue
            elif again == 'n' or again == 'N':
                is_user_turn = False
                break
        else:
            human_score = 1
            human_rand = str(human_rand)
            print("roll: " + human_rand)
            human_rand = int(human_rand)
            print("You rolled a 1. Turn over.")
            human_score = str(human_score)
            print("Current Score: " + human_score)
            human_score = int(human_score)
            return human_score
    if human_rand == 1:
        human_rand = str(human_rand)
        print("roll: " + human_rand)
        human_rand = int(human_rand)
        print("You rolled a 1. Turn over.")
        human_score = 1
        human_score = str(human_score)
        print("Current Score: " + human_score)
        human_score = int(human_score)
        return human_score
    else:
        return human_score
elif is_user_turn == False:
    computer_rand = roll_die()
    while computer_rand != 1:
        computer_score = computer_score + computer_rand
        if computer_score != 0:
            computer_rand = str(computer_rand)
            print("roll: " + computer_rand)
            computer_rand = int(computer_rand)
            if computer_score <= COMPUTER_HOLD:
                computer_rand = roll_die()
                continue
            else:
                computer_score = str(computer_score)
                print("*computer holds on " + computer_score + "*")
                computer_score = int(computer_score)
                is_user_turn = True
                break
        else:
            computer_score = 1
            computer_rand = str(computer_rand)
            print("roll: " + computer_rand)
            computer_rand = int(computer_rand)
            print("The computer rolled a 1. Turn over.")
            return computer_score
    if computer_rand == 1:
        computer_rand = str(computer_rand)
        print("rollclea " + computer_rand)
        computer_rand = int(computer_rand)
        print("The computer rolled a 1. Turn over.")
        computer_score = 1
        return computer_score
    else:
        return computer_score
```

> The function take_turn() stores a value of the scores. 
>   report_points shows the total of scores. The loop should exit once the placer or total persay reached the GAME_END_POINTS. Instead it is letting the computer do a dice roll after the user already won the game. I've removed the if-else statements from the code block to provide a clean slate for debugging

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Fix it. It matters in Python.

Comment: `while(user_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS or computer_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS):` This continues while _either_ is true. Change to `and` so it only continues while _both_ are true.

Comment: Hello! I've fixed the indentation and changed the or an a however after I get a score of say 10 or more, the program still allows me to accumulate more points which is fine but when I say no to end my turn, it lets the computer take one more turn before exiting the loop

Comment: The indentation is not fixed. The line after `def take_turn(is_user_turn, COMPUTER_HOLD):` is indented the same as it is, which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(user_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS or computer_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS):
```

This will continue while *either* is true. So, even if `user_plcr > GAME_END_POINTS`, it will keep going until `computer_plcr > GAME_END_POINTS`. You want to quit when either one is false. In other words, continue while *both* are true.

```
while (user_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS and computer_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS):
```

Also, inside the `while`, if the user scores more than `GAME_END_POINTS`, the computer still goes. So you need to check the user's score before allowing the computer to take a turn.

```
while(user_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS and computer_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS):
    print_current_player(is_user_turn)
    user_total = take_turn(is_user_turn,COMPUTER_HOLD)
    user_plcr = user_plcr + user_total
    if user_plcr <= GAME_END_POINTS:
        is_user_turn = get_next_player(is_user_turn)
        print_current_player(is_user_turn)
        computer_total = take_turn(is_user_turn,COMPUTER_HOLD)
        computer_plcr = computer_plcr + computer_total
    report_points(user_plcr,computer_plcr)
    print("\n")
    is_user_turn = get_next_player(is_user_turn)
```

Comment: Thanks Johnny. Looks like I should be paying more attention in my discrete structures course

Comment: These were just logic errors. If you want a good critique of the code, finish it up and post over at [codereview.se].